# Error: Network Error - Expo (React Native)

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I've been struggling for the past few days trying to resolve the issue with all my `axios` requests. No matter what I change, I keep getting the error:

> [Error: Network Error]

When this error happens, it closes the application into the background of the phone but doesn't crash. There is not other error logs or warnings so it's I'm finding it hard to debug the issue.

This is not being sent to localhost, this is sent a public domain as I know there are people having issues with localhost and having to switch to use IP address. However it's happening when I'm using public domain.

Has anyone come across this with their expo build on android before?

**Update:**

The APIs work in postman, so it's only an issue when sending requests via the `expo` application.

**Update Fixed:**

Finally found the issue flagging:

```
canceled due to java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method toString(Z)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lokhttp3/Cookie;
```

I had to had the following to build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.4.1'
```

Comment: If your request is sent to http://localhost… Try to replace localhost with your local ip adress. And the same for your api.

Comment: @J.dev - I've updated my question, it's not being sent to localhost, it's actually be sent to a public domain.

Comment: Does the public domain use the cors ?

Comment: @J.dev Nope it doesn't, so i'm really stumped at what could be the issue :)

Comment: Can you reach a simple api like jsonplaceholder from your app ?

Comment: @J.dev - Yes i've just tried that, so it can reach other places just strange that it can't reach mine

Comment: Maybe try to reach it via postman, you'll probably get more details in the response

Comment: @J.dev - It works via postman, it's just not working via the `expo` application

Comment: The last thing I can see could be a typo or a missing / trailing slash in your url. Let me kow when you'll find the solution. Good luck!

Comment: @J.dev - Finally found the issue, I've updated my question to have the answer

Comment: Happy you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Android dont accept HTTP protocol Api so keep sure you are using a HTTPS protocol  Api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).